# Retrofit, request get with not-necessary parameters

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a GET request like this
http://176.57.71.76/api/user_vacancy?employment=full_time&time=7&house=0&sort=name

but, sometimes I do need to put query parameters `employment`, `time` and so on.

Now, I have this

```
@GET("user_vacancy")
fun getVacanciesWithFilter(): Single<VacanciesListResponse>
```

Do I need to write a separate request for each parameter, or can I bypass this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to write separate code for each query parameter. `Retrofit` supports optional query parameters. Here is the `Java` code for your example. If you pass null for any parameter, `Retrofit` will omit that query while forming the request.

```
@GET("user_vacancy") Single<VacanciesListResponse> getVacanciesWithFilter(
    @Query("employment") String employmentType, 
    @Query("time") int time
);
```

More info [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-optional-query-parameters). Using `QueryMap` is also a good approach as mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 3):

Add your query/filter as per you need

```
val hashMap = HashMap<String, String>()
            hashMap.put("employment", "full_time")
            hashMap.put("time", "7")
            hashMap.put("house", "0")
            hashMap.put("sort", "name")
```

suppose you do not need house and sort filter then you don't need to put them on hashmap

like,

```
val hashMap = HashMap<String, String>()
            hashMap.put("employment", "full_time")
            hashMap.put("time", "7")
```

then calling your api

```
apiService.getVacanciesWithFilter(hashMap)
```

In your API service class

```
@GET("user_vacancy")
    fun getVacanciesWithFilter(
        @QueryMap hashMap: Map<String, String>
    ): Single<VacanciesListResponse>
```